# i want to convert this to a lat/lng array from a string so that i can use it to track users movements. or is there anyway by using json?

Tags: android, gps, location

here is the input:

> [lat/lng: (10.9011873,76.9026255),lat/lng:
>   (10.9011873,76.9026255),lat/lng: (10.9011873,76.9026255),lat/lng:
>   (10.9011873,76.9026255),lat/lng: (10.9011873,76.9026255),lat/lng:
>   (10.9011873,76.9026255),lat/lng: (10.94011873,76.29026255),lat/lng:
>   (12.9011873,86.9026255),lat/lng: (15.9011873,76.29026255),lat/lng:
>   (10.90131873,26.9026255),lat/lng: (10.901187233,76.904226255)]

I'm getting this input and uploading in **Sqllite** database. Then retrieving it later for tracking the user.. If he is on the right path or not.
My datatbase is returning the whole array as a string which i need to convert it into a lat/lng array.

Comment: For me it is clear what he asked. As the answers below showed. No need to put on hold

Comment: Question is as clear as it is. Simple conversion of a lat/lng array to string and vice versa. Question also has been answered. I don't know why the question is on hold!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy:

```
    String answer = "[lat/lng: (10.9011873,76.9026255),lat/lng: (10.9011873,76.9026255),lat/lng: (10.9011873,76.9026255),lat/lng: (10.9011873,76.9026255),lat/lng: (10.9011873,76.9026255),lat/lng: (10.9011873,76.9026255),lat/lng: (10.94011873,76.29026255),lat/lng: (12.9011873,86.9026255),lat/lng: (15.9011873,76.29026255),lat/lng: (10.90131873,26.9026255),lat/lng: (10.901187233,76.904226255)]";

       ArrayList<Location> arrayListLatLng;
      String answer = "";
     answer = answer.replace("lat/lng: (" , "");
     answer = answer.replace(")" , "");
    String[] arrayLatLng = answer.split(",");

       for(int i = 0 ; i <arrayLatLng.length ; i++ ){
        Location j = new Location(rendomName);
        j.setLatitude(arrayLatLng[i]);
        j.setLongitude(arrayLatLng[i+1]);
        arrayListLatLng.add(new Location(j))
            }

Location A  = arrayListLatLng.get(0);
//make some code here with the A
```

HOPE its help you :)